# Is using reinterpret_cast (in a non-active-member) to cast to the active member of an union UB?

Tags: c++

Look at this snippet:

```
#include <new>

struct Storage {
    int value;

    Storage() : value(0) { }
};

struct Field {
    void set(int v) {
        reinterpret_cast<Storage *>(this)->value = v;
    }
};

union Foo {
    Storage storage;
    Field field;

    Foo() {
        new(&storage) Storage;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.field.set(1);
}
```

In `main`, `f` has the active member `storage`. Then, on a different member (`field`), there is a function call (`set`), which casts `this` into the type of the active member.

Does this code have UB?

Comment: I don't see why you think this wouldn't be UB.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is UB or not such a design seems to be flawed. The only valid case of casting of `this` pointer to something else inside of that class method I can think of would be an implementation of CRTP.

Comment: Accessing an inactive member is UB, doesn't matter how you access it.

Comment: I'd say it is defined. Structs and unions allocate all the memory while creating em.

Comment: @StoryTeller: calling a function on it count as accessing it?

Comment: @SvSv - This isn't a matter of opinion. C++ a has standard that defines how a program should behave. This is UB

Comment: @geza - It's a member. Accessing a member evaluates the object. So yes, it's an access.

Comment: @StoryTeller: even if this class is an empty one, so "accessing" it is meaningless, as there is nothing to access? Btw, what does it mean "evaluates" the object in this context?

Comment: ["Evaluates" means this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#1). And yes, "even" and "even" and "even" doesn't make this any less UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller An evaluation does not necessarily access an object. That's why the evaluation of `storage` in the OP's code as an lvalue is fine.

Comment: @hvd - Calling a member function on a glvalue that doesn't designate a living object (and the non-active union member is not a living object) is UB. There's nothing more to it. This question has several layers of UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller: what if I call `new(&f.field) Field`? Here, I've written `f.field`, which is UB, as `f.field` is not an active member. How can one change the active member then?

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm well aware of that (see my answer). But it's undefined because it's explicitly stated to be undefined, not because it's an access.

Comment: @hvd - `f.field` is undefined on its own, the guaranteed evaluation is what makes it undefined. As opposed to `sizeof(f.field)` being okay due to the unevaluated context.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, it's not. `auto x = &f.field;` would evaluate `f.field` as an lvalue and would be well-defined. The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would be what causes an access, but there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in a call to a member function.

Comment: @geza - Placement new will make it the active member. But unless you add a pseudo destructor call for `f.storage`, it's UB from the other way around.

Comment: @hvd - You are really splitting hairs here. The very quote you presented is a clear intent by the committee to treat the call of a member function as an "access". In a uniform manner to data members.

Comment: @StoryTeller If it were an access, the quote I presented would be completely and utterly useless because it would already be undefined. The whole reason why that paragraph is needed is because there's no access.

Comment: @hvd - You are clearly ignoring my air quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `f.field.set` violates [class.mfct.non-static]p2:

> If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior is undefined.

You're calling a member function `set` of a class `Field` when you do not have an object of type `Field`.

Comment: `f.field` certainly is an object of type `Field`. It's just not alive.

Comment: @aschepler No, there's no object of type `Field` at all there. The standard contains an exhaustive enumeration of the ways in which an object can be created. Storage being available is not enough. C++ is not C.

Comment: But [basic.life]5-6 do discuss properties of "an object" outside of its lifetime. Or if you say it's not an object, your quote cannot apply.

Comment: @aschepler The quote applies because there is *an* object there, it's just not of type `Field`, it's of type `Storage`. [basic.life] is about the lifetime of an object and only applies when you actually have an object. It applies for instance to declared variables for which the initialisation has not been performed.

Comment: @aschepler But you do raise an interesting point. Given `auto *p = (X *) malloc(sizeof(X));`, `p->f();` is clearly intended to be undefined for any non-static member function `f()`, even though `malloc` has been explicitly stated not to be sufficient to create any object.

Comment: Okay, now I see your point. But what would you say about http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d40b2a2069faf585 ?

Comment: @aschepler Currently, I believe `u.b = B{};` has UB (you'd need placement new) unless the active union member is already `b`, but there is a proposal to make that valid. Aside from that, good question, I don't have an answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

This program has undefined behavior because you may not call a non-static member function of an object that is not currently alive.  C++14 [basic.life]/6:

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways....  The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - ...
> - the glvalue is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object
> - ...

Comment: This seems a legit answer, too, upvoted, but I cannot accept two answers, unfortunately.